# Why rebuild of Kotlin application removes target class files in Eclipse?

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, maven, kotlin, m2eclipse

I'm trying to setup an app written in Kotlin, built on Maven and using Spring Boot in Eclipse.

I manage to run the application only if I do Maven build of the project which generates class files in `target/classes` dir. If I do clean the project then Eclipse rebuilds it automatically and removes all class files from `target/classes` dir.

I think that re-build of the project should re-compile class files in `target/classes` directory, not just to remove them. Otherwise it means that I need to re-build project as Maven on each code change which I seems to be a wrong way to go.

Please point me the correct way to setup a Kotlin - Maven - Spring Boot project in Eclipse.

My setup is:

- Eclipse is 4.26.0.
- Maven EMBEDDED 3.8.6.
- Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse 0.8.24 (it causes intallation of Enhanced Kotlin for Eclipse plugin).
- Spring Tools 4 - 4.17.2.RELEASE.
- OpenJDK 11.0.2.

What I did:

1. Installed all the above (Eclipse, plugins, JDK and etc).
2. Imported the project as a Maven project in Eclipse: [github link](https://github.com/ssanchozz/maven-kotlin-spring).

[Import dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU8Uw.png)

3. Right click on DemoApplication.kt -> Run As -> 1 Kotlin Application. I got an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt
```

4. Right click on pom.xml -> Run As -> 2 Maven build...
5. Goals: clean install -> Run.
6. After that I see in `{project dir}\target\classes\com\example\demo` class files were generated.
7. If then I do right click on DemoApplication.kt -> Run As -> 1 Kotlin Application it runs OK.
8. If I click on Project -> Clean... (with Build Automatically ON) - all files from `{project dir}\target\classes\com\example\demo` got removed and I again start at point 3.

I tried couple configuration options, but they didn't help:

1. Making Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Building -> Output folder -> Scrub output folders when cleaning projects OFF doesn't help - class files still got removed.
2. In Package Explorer -> Kotlin Runtime Library there is a virtual directory kotlin_bin which has all class files. I tried to setup it as Dependencies:

[Run Configuration dependencies setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CARA0.png)

But it fails to run then with the below error:

[Error when run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eJet.png)

Comment: When the Import is done, where is the output folder according to the project's Java Build Path?

Comment: Java Build Path is `{project dir}/target/classes`.

Comment: Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse 0.8.24 has been released 2018. Better use the [Enhanced Kotlin for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enhanced-kotlin-eclipse) plugin for current Eclipse versions.

Comment: Looks like when you install Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse automatically Enchanced Kotlin for Eclipse is being installed. I'm even not sure that it's possible to install them separately, but will try. Plugin was released in 2018, but I see that last updates hapenned on 13 Jan 2023. And in one minute an update happened in Enhanced Kotlin for Eclipse. Looks like one person is contributing to both of them.

Comment: When you install Enchanced Kotlin for Eclipse, automatically Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse is installed and vice versa, so this doesn't help.

Comment: It seems the _Enchanced Kotlin for Eclipse_ plugin is the newer version of the _Kotlin Plugin_ from JetBrains. So not two plugins, but the same plugin of different versions from different update sites with different Marketplace entries (see _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_). Please update your question using the newest Kotlin plugin.

Comment: As the description of _Enchanced Kotlin for Eclipse_ says, it's based on _Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse_. Maybe that's why the one causes installation of the other. @howlger